# MVC 3 User saved with entity passed down from front end

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, model-binding

I have a scenario where I create "Machine" entities that are associated with the logged in user (windows authentication) that created them. The user is only ever created in the database once they have created at least one Machine entity.

I'm using model binding on the create Machine form. The Machine model has an associated User entity, a custom one that looks like this:

```
public class User
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("User")]
    public string Username { get; set; }

    public string Email { get; set; }

    public int SectorId { get; set; }
    public Sector Sector { get; set; }

    public List<Machine> Machines { get; set; }
}
```

So far, in the create machine view I have created a hidden input for the user name using the following:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.User.Username, new { User.Identity.Name })
```

But I'm finding that this is not populated in the model when it is returned to the HttpPost create handler.

I was wondering how I might be able to pass the username down with the model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, the problem you're having with your `HiddenFor()` method call is that the second parameter is supposed to be an `object` for htmlAttributes.  So your method call isn't correct. ([MSDN Reference for the `HiddenFor()` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee703622.aspx)):

```
public static MvcHtmlString HiddenFor<TModel, TProperty>(
    this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper,
    Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression,
    Object htmlAttributes
)
```

Why are you trying to populate this within the View?  Take this logic to the controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult GetUser(User newUser)
{
    newUser.UserName = User.Identity.Name;

    // now do something with the passed in model
}
```

Comment: How do you see the GetUser method being used? An ajax call from the view to populate the hidden user input?

Comment: You were right about the overload of HiddenFor I was using, I wanted the one with the single lambda argument. As for passing the user to the view I new up a Machine with the user already set inside it and that is then populated on the create form when it is loaded. Cheers!